# SQL filter for lowest price

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge table of pricing data, with the following columns

```
source, product, term, miles, price
```

The data looks something like this

```
LL, PH, 3, 10000, 100.00
BA, PH, 3, 10000, 200.00
LL, CH, 3, 10000, 300.00
BA, CH, 3, 10000, 400.00
```

I need to create a query to filter the rows to show only the line with the lowest price for each unique source/product/term/miles combination. So in the above example i'd like to end up with:

```
LL, PH, 3, 10000, 100.00
BA, PH, 3, 10000, 200.00
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the code you've wrote so far?

Comment: Use the `Group By  source, product, term,miles`  and `select source, product, term,miles, MIN(price)`

Comment: Your expected output does not match your sample data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f10f1/1/0)

```
SELECT
    source, product, term, miles, price
FROM(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMER() OVER(PARTITION BY source, product, term, miles ORDER BY price)
    FROM [your_table]
)t
WHERE RN = 1
```

Or as per Coder of Code's comment, you could use `MIN()` and `GROUP BY`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f10f1/2/0)

```
SELECT
    source, product, term, miles, price = MIN(price)
FROM [your_table]
GROUP BY source, product, term, miles
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return rows where no lower price exists for the same source:

```
select source, product, term, miles, price
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.source = t2.source
                    and t2.price < t1.price)
```

If you want the source/product combos with lowest price, add product to the sub-select's condition:

```
select source, product, term, miles, price
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.source = t2.source
                    and t1.product = t2.product 
                    and t2.price < t1.price)
```

etc.

If there's a tie, both rows will be returned!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    source, product, term, miles, MIN(price) AS price
FROM [table_name]
GROUP BY source, product, term, miles
```